# transfer date into input field from one asp form into another using session state

Tags: javascript, asp.net, webforms, session-state

I need to transfer date from one asp form to another based on some checks. 
In the source page I do the check and send as following:

```
if (txtFinalized.Text == "" && rblPhysicalrecords.SelectedValue=="1" && ddlResponsibility.SelectedIndex == 5)
            {
                //String s = Request.QueryString["finlalisationDate"] = txtFinalized.Text;
                Session["finlalisationDate"] = txtFinalized.Text;
            }
```

Then I try to read the value in the target form but so far I can't get the resut inserted into the input field as I need.

```
 txtFinalised.Text = (string)(Session["finlalisationDate"]);
```

Do I need to write a method in javascript to fetch the result and insert it to the field and if yes how do I do that?

Comment: your `if` condition says `txtFinalized.Text` this field must be empty. Then you storing `txtFinalized.Text` same empty field in session. How do you expect Some value in next form if it is empty at first form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your condition block has a flaw, it says txtFinalized must be empty to set a value to your session variable.

For learning and and understand session you could write your code like this...

```
//remove txtFinalized from condition
if (rblPhysicalrecords.SelectedValue=="1" && ddlResponsibility.SelectedIndex == 5)
{
    //check if textFinalized NOT is null or empty
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty)
    {
        Session["finlalisationDate"] = txtFinalized.Text;
    }
    //if textFinalized is empty set session to a value just to see some text
    else
    {
        Session["finlalisationDate"] = "n/a";
    }
}
```

Now when you load your second form you will always see something in your textFinalized textbox and from what you see you know if the user made some input in the first form.

Comment: The thing is that txtFinalized.Text; is a date therefor, I get undefined when I try to retrive it in the target page. I have to convert it to date but it did not work:    Session["finlalisationDate"] = txtFinalized.Text = (phase.Finalised != null) ? phase.Finalised.Value.ToString("dd.MMM.yyyy", ci) : "";

Comment: @Mindan That can be solved by storing txtFinalized as normal and then retrieving your date like Convert.Date(Session["finlalisationDate"])

Answer (score 0):

You can modify your condition block like below

```
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtFinalized.Text) && rblPhysicalrecords.SelectedValue=="1" && ddlResponsibility.SelectedIndex == 5)
            {
                //String s = Request.QueryString["finlalisationDate"] = txtFinalized.Text;
                Session["finlalisationDate"] = txtFinalized.Text;
            }
```